# What is the significance of Suutak?

Tags: rituals, death

When a family member dies, generally every member of that family observes a 13-day mourning period called `Suutak`.

What is the significance of observing this period? meaning.. a person is not allowed to do prayers or Aarti or visit temple, but he/she can all other activities.

Do we have something mentioned in the `Vedas` or `Upanishads` about `Suutak`?

Comment: Related question - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/37833/why-do-hindus-mourns-for-13-days

Comment: Yes - this answers my question. Thanks.